# Hyperas loss function for regression problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regression, hyperas

I've built a model using Keras for solving the regression problem. I want to perform a hyperparameter optimization on this model. As metrics I used `val_mean_absolute_error`. In the example, only classification problem is covered (available on https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas)

```
validation_acc = np.amax(result.history['val_acc']) 
print('Best validation acc of epoch:', validation_acc)
return {'loss': -validation_acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}
```

How to adapt this code for a regression problem (for using `val_mean_absolute_error` as a metrics)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For regression problems, we usually do not define a separate metric, using the loss itself to assess model performance (the lower the better); so, assuming you are using `mae` as your loss, and you have compiled your model as

```
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer={{choice(['rmsprop', 'adam', 'sgd'])}})
```

this is how you should modify the code from the linked example:

```
#get the lowest validation loss of the training epochs
validation_loss = np.amin(result.history['val_loss']) 
print('Best validation loss of epoch:', validation_loss)
return {'loss': validation_loss, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}
```

It's true that some people add a compilation argument for `metrics=['mae']` in similar cases, but this is unnecessary.